# Query to get user info and list of roles in a single row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been asked to develop a query on Postgresql 9.2, which I have only limited exposure to, that will return a users information (from the `users` table) along with their roles (from the `role` table - a user may have many roles) in a single row. What I have is:

```
[user table] --> [user_role table] <-- [role table]
users table: id, firstname, lastname, username, ... ; 
user_role table: id, user_id (fk to user); 
role_id (fk to role); role table: id, name;
```

What I need to get is:

```
users.firstname, users.lastname, users.username, users....(other user info),
role.name, role.name (one role name for each role a user has).
```

Comment: please add the *real* definitions. I don't read shorthand notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, I expect:

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, array_agg(r.name)
FROM user u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_role ur ON (u.id = ur.user_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN role r ON (ur.role_id = r.id)
GROUP BY u.id;
```

You might want `string_agg` instead of `array_agg` depending on desired output format.

It's untested since you didn't provide sample data. If you're on an old PostgreSQL version you will need to explicitly specify every column of `user` that appears in the `SELECT` list in the `GROUP BY` list too.

Note that the roles are returned in a single column. That's necessary; there's no support for dynamic width tables where different rows can have different widths. You can use pretty much any format you like for the result - delimited text, xml, json, hstore, array, etc.

Your `user_role.id` column is completely unnecessary and should probably be replaced with `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, role_id)` unless you're dealing with stupid ORMs that can't cope with composite primary keys.

Comment: Thany you worked great - did change array_agg to string_agg. Also thanks for the comment on user_role.id - this is not my database but I will take to comment to the user.